# Can I have @BeforeTest and @AfterTest run for only a group of Tests?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng

I am building a test framework for a project with multiple modules. Currently, I have two tests in my testng.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name = "listener-class" />
  </listeners>
  <test thread-count="5" name="frontEnd">
  <parameter name="URL" value="front-end-url" />
    <classes>
      <class name="frontendTestRunner"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  <test thread-count="5" name="Backend">
  <parameter name="URL" value="back-end-url" /> 
    <classes>
      <class name="backendtestrunner"/>
    </classes>
  </test>  <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

For both of these tests, the before and after conditions are different.

Is there is way I can have @BeforeTest and @AfterTest methods run for only one test say "frontEnd" and different @BeforeTest and @AfterTest methods for the second one - "Backend".

Currently I am using two different Cucumber testrunners to accomplish this. But I want to do it using only one testrunner.

Here are my two TestRunners:

```
@CucumberOptions(
            features = "src/test/java/com/frontEnd",
            glue = "com/stepDefinitions/frontEnd",
            tags = {"~@ignore"}
        )
public class FrontEndTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @Parameters( {"URL"})
    @BeforeTest
    public static void setup(String url) throws IOException {
        TestConfiguration.initialise(true);
        Pages.initialise();
        TestConfiguration.getHomePageUrl(url);
    }

    /**
     * This class runs after the completion of the final test. It populates the reports and closes the browser driver. 
     */
    @AfterTest
    public static void after() {
        Browser.close();        
    }

}
```

And

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "src/test/java/com/backEnd",
        glue = "com/stepDefinitions/backEnd"
    )
public class BackEndTestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

    @BeforeTest
    public static void setup() throws IOException {
        TestConfiguration.initialise(true);
        Pages.initialise();
    }

    /**
     * This class runs after the completion of the final test. It logs the user out and closes the browser driver. 
     */
    @AfterTest
    public static void after() {
        Browser.close();        
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can only one TestRunner and somehow still be able to run correct Begin and After conditions for the two set of features?

Basically I need to be able to group two sets of Features and call two different @BeforeTest and @AfterTest methods depending on the which group the Feature belongs to.

Comment: How about having two test classes...?

Answer (score 2):

I've put together a sample maven project for you which keeps a single test runner file and allows you to keep your front and back end files separate (or you can combine them, if you want)

**In src/test/java:**

1. Add a package called "features"

   - Create a file called "backend.feature"
   - Create a file called "frontend.feature"
2. Add a package called "runners"

   - Create a class file called "myRunner.java"
3. Add a package called "stepDefinitions"

   - Create a class file called "backendSteps.java"
   - Create a class file called "frontendSteps.java"
4. Update your maven and testng xml files

---

**backend.feature**

```
Feature: Back End.

@backend
Scenario: Back end scenario.
Given Back end given
When  Back end when
Then  Back end then
```

---

---

**frontend.feature**

```
Feature: Front End.

@frontend
Scenario: Front end scenario.
Given Front end given
When  Front end when
Then  Front end then
```

---

---

**myRunner.java**

```
package runners;



import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;



@CucumberOptions(features   = "src/test/java/features",
                 glue       = "stepDefinitions")
public class myRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests
{
}
```

---

---

**backendSteps.java**

```
package stepDefinitions;



import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;



public class backendSteps
{
    @Before("@backend")
    public void setUp()
    {
        System.out.println("@Before for back end");
    }


    @After("@backend")
    public void tearDown()
    {
        System.out.println("@After for back end");
    }


    //  back end tests
    @Given("^Back end given$")
    public void Back_end_given()
    {
        System.out.println("Back end given");
    }


    @When("^Back end when$")
    public void Back_end_when()
    {
        System.out.println("Back end when");
    }


    @Then("^Back end then$")
    public void Back_end_then()
    {
        System.out.println("Back end then");
    }
}
```

---

---

**frontendSteps.java**

```
package stepDefinitions;



import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;



public class frontendSteps
{
    @Before("@frontend")
    public void setUp()
    {
        System.out.println("@Before for front end");
    }


    @After("@frontend")
    public void tearDown()
    {
        System.out.println("@After for front end");
    }


    //  front end tests
    @Given("^Front end given$")
    public void Front_end_given()
    {
        System.out.println("Front end given");
    }


    @When("^Front end when$")
    public void Front_end_when()
    {
        System.out.println("Front end when");
    }


    @Then("^Front end then$")
    public void Front_end_then()
    {
        System.out.println("Front end then");
    }
}
```

---

---

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>YourGroupID</groupId>
    <artifactId>YourArtifactID</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>TestNgCucumber.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

---

---

**TestNgCucumber.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">


<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="runners.myRunner" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

---

---

**Output to console**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0
@Before for back end
Back end given
Back end when
Back end then
@After for back end
@Before for front end
Front end given
Front end when
Front end then
@After for front end

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

---

Alternatively, you can comment out the @Before and @After methods from the 2 step definition files, and replace them with a separate file in the "stepDefinitions" package, like so:

**Hooks.java**

```
package stepDefinitions;



import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;



public class Hooks
{
    @Before("@frontend")
    public void setUpFrontend()
    {
        System.out.println("@Before for front end");
    }


    @Before("@backend")
    public void setUpBackend()
    {
        System.out.println("@Before for back end");
    }


    @After("@frontend or @backend")
    public void tearDown()
    {
        System.out.println("@After for front end and back end");
    }
}
```

---

---

**Output to console**

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0
@Before for back end
Back end given
Back end when
Back end then
@After for front end and back end
@Before for front end
Front end given
Front end when
Front end then
@After for front end and back end

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

---

Comment: Actually that is what I am doing. I have one testng.xml which has two tests and calling two TestRunner classes. I have 2 sets of Cucumber feature files. One set for front end and the other for backend. Both set have different urls and different before and after conditions. To segregate these two set, I have placed them in two different packages and running them using two different TestRunners. Is there a way I can have only one TestRunner and somehow segregate these two set of Cucumber features?

Comment: I am pasting my two Cucumber TestRunners in my question.

Comment: @Connoisseur, I've completely redone my answer, I'm pretty sure this is what you're looking for.
Its actually based on what user2391218 suggested

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are using testng hooks instead of cucumber hooks. You can achivee this using cucumber hooks easily. Place the cucumber hooks Class inside Step Definition package. @before and @after block can be tagged so that method inside hooks are called only for scenarios with that specific tag. For example check the code below 
**beforeFrontEndScenario** and **afterFrontEndScenario** is called only for scenaios with tag @frontEnd. By following this you will be able to have single runner file and still have seperate hooks for frondend and backend scenarios.

Here is a example of cucucmber hook class

```
public class Hooks {

 @Before
    public void beforeScenario(){
        System.out.println("method is executed before all scenario");
    } 

 @After
    public void afterScenario(){
        System.out.println("method is executed after all scenario");
    }

 @Before("@frontEnd")
public void beforeFrontEndScenarios(){
    System.out.println("before block called for scenario with tag frontEnd");
} 

  @After("@frontEnd")
  public void afterFrontEndScenarios(){
    System.out.println("after block called for scenario with tag frontEnd");
  } 


}
```